# Replace string repeatedly

Tags: bash

When I execute command

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan  | grep ESSID
```

I get the result:

```
ESSID:"DHS_3RD_FLOOR" ESSID:"MAXTA" ESSID:"MAXTA_5THWL" ESSID:"OPENSTACK" ESSID:"IOT" ESSID:"ved_opa" ESSID:"dlink" ESSID:"WifiFeazt"
```

But I want output as:(without ESSID:")

```
DHS_3RD_FLOOR MAXTA MAXTA_5THWL OPENSTACK IOT ved_opa dlink WifiFeazt
```

I googled but I have no idea how to do it.

Any advice?

Comment: Does `sudo iwlist wlan0 scan  | grep ESSID` result is one line or multiple line?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(ESSID:|")//g'
```

or

```
sed 's/\(ESSID:\|"\)//g'
```

or

```
perl -pe 's/(?:ESSID:|")//g'
```

or in pure bash:

```
str=$(sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID)
str=${str//ESSID:/}
echo ${str//\"/}
```

Output:

```
DHS_3RD_FLOOR MAXTA MAXTA_5THWL OPENSTACK IOT ved_opa dlink WifiFeazt
```

Comment: Seeing you are on a roll: `awk '{gsub(/ESSID:/,"")}1'`...

Answer (score 2):

In awk, i would do like

```
$ .... | awk '{gsub(/ESSID:|"/,"")}1'
DHS_3RD_FLOOR MAXTA MAXTA_5THWL OPENSTACK IOT ved_opa dlink WifiFeazt
```

Comment: `awk 'gsub(/ESSID:|"/,"")'` ensures only lines that contained ESSID are printed(which means the grep is not needed)

Answer (score 1):

POSIXly:

```
sed -e 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)"/\1 /g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `grep`:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -oP ':"\K[^"]+?(?=")'
DHS_3RD_FLOOR
MAXTA
MAXTA_5THWL
OPENSTACK
IOT
ved_opa
dlink
WifiFeazt
```

The `-o` flag means "print only the matching portion of the line", when more than one matches are found, all will be printed. The `-P` enables [PCREs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) which give us `\K` ("ignore everything matched up to here") and [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). These allow to match depending on the following characters but without including said characters in the match itself. So, the regular expression means "look for `:"` and discard it, then match as many non-`"` as possible until the next `"`".

To get everything on one line, pass it through `tr`:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -oP ':"\K[^"]+?(?=")' | tr '\n' ' '
DHS_3RD_FLOOR MAXTA MAXTA_5THWL OPENSTACK IOT ved_opa dlink WifiFeazt $
```

Or, to get a trailing newline:

```
$ echo $(sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep -oP ':"\K[^"]+?(?=")' | tr '\n' ' ')
DHS_3RD_FLOOR MAXTA MAXTA_5THWL OPENSTACK IOT ved_opa dlink WifiFeazt
```